# Why does Chrome on Mac skip the confirm dialog in this bit of code?

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome

I have a pretty simple Javascript/AJAX function with a confirm dialog so the user has to confirm before the code executes:

```
function leaveLeague(league_id) {

    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to leave this league?')) {

        if(window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("curr_leagues").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax/leave_league.php?league_id=" + league_id, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }

}
```

Now, the code works in all browser on Windows, including Chrome. However, I've received complaints from users that the confirm dialog is skipped in the latest version of Chrome on Mac OS. The function just executes without a confirm dialog. I don't have anything with Mac so I can't test myself, but there's no reason for people to lie to me so I'm assuming the problem is real.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

The function is called from a link using a click event:

```
<a onClick='leaveLeague(2);'>Leave League</a>
```

Comment: You are missing an important detail: How is `leaveLeague` called?

Comment: Through a simple click event, I've added it to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Cancel the click event of the link

```
<a href="#" onclick='leaveLeague(2);return false;'>Leave League</a>
```

Comment: How would that change anything for the confirm dialog, I don't understand.

Comment: The click event on a link may cause the page to reload which means the code would not fire. Cancelling the click means the default action will not happen. Also add in an `href="#"` just to make sure it does not have issues with that missing.

Comment: Browsers shouldn't redirect if a dialog box is active, but it could do anyway.